# Cone size for Shimano Type D on Schwinn Cruiser

Tags: maintenance

What size wrench do I need for the rear hub on my Schwinn cruiser?  It is a Shimano Type D. Also, what grease is recommended that I might be able to by locally.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a 15mm [cone wrench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_wrench) and a 17mm regular wrench. If you're going to buy a cone wrench, the 13/15mm double-ended wrench covers most hubs.

I recommend any PTFE-based bearing lubricant. You can buy a huge tub of it from an automotive store for very cheap.